# Bash example of testing if a secure IMAP connection works?

Tags: monitoring, imap

I want to add a test for a secure IMAP connection, authentication being part of it.

That I would run using a cron job. If anything wrong happens I do want to get and email, so if it goes well it should have no output.

Does anyone have such a script, bash, python,...?

Comment: You could use openssl s_client, as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959461/how-to-talk-to-imap-server-in-bash-via-openssl

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.example.com:993 -quiet <<EOF
some command
another command
EOF
```

to connect to the remote server.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nagios-compatible plugin for IMAP available [here](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Protocols/IMAP4-and-POP3/check_imap_login-Plugin/details). You can use that from a command-line without implementing Nagios.  I believe it is a python script that you could repurpose.